# split xml file with multiple value using xslt

Tags: xslt-2.0

trying to split the xml file having multiple elements into separate xml having different elements.

Input File:

```
<Person>
 <firstname>ABC</firstname>
 <lastname>ABC</lastname>
 <address>address1</address>
 <address>address2</address>
 <city>city</city>
 <state>state</state>
 <currency>currency1</currency>
 <currency>currency2</currency>
</Person>

Need to split above file into two files as
Output file-1

<Person>
 <firstname>ABC</firstname>
 <lastname>ABC</lastname>
 <address>address1</address> 
 <city>city</city>
 <state>state</state>
 <currency>currency1</currency> 
</Person>
```

Output file -2

```
<Person>
 <firstname>ABC</firstname>
 <lastname>ABC</lastname>
 <address>address2</address> 
 <city>city</city>
 <state>state</state>
 <currency>currency2</currency> 
</Person>
```

Comment: Will there always be two address and currency elements? Or various, with an unknown number of elements?

Comment: there will be more than 2 elements but all of them will be known.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic solution that outputs N files where N is the maximum number of same-name children elements, where file N contains the Nth instance of each element name if there are at least N, or the first one otherwise:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
  <xsl:variable name="names" select="distinct-values(*/name())"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="1 to max(
            for $name in $names return count(*[name()=$name]))"/>
    <xsl:variable name="n" select="."/>
    <xsl:result-document href="file{.}">
      <xsl:element name="{name($this)}">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$this/*" group-by="name()">
          <xsl:copy-of select="(current-group()[$n], .)[1]"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This should do what you want with the example input you have shown, but whether it does the right thing with any other input is anyone's guess, because you have under-specified the requirements.